# Finding files with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python (3.4) I know you can find a navigate to a file with `C:\somefolder\etc.\somefile.txt` and I also know you can access `somefile.txt` if you are in `somefolder` by using `etc.\somefile.txt`.

However, I don't know of a way to find a file in a parallel folder.
As in (from cmd prompt)

```
dir
folder 1
folder 2
```

If you were in `folder 1`, you would have to use `C:\blah\blah\folder 2\somefile.txt` to get `somefile.txt` from `folder 2`. There is no way to access what is in said parallel folder without using the full path, right?

Comment: you just need `../folder 2/somefile.txt`

Comment: Can you use `../folder 2/somefile.txt`?

Comment: Well if you use "os.path", you don't "navigate" per say... ?

Comment: I was using `subprocess.call('path')`

Comment: Have you tried `..`? My comment probably seems confusing since I posted at the same time as Kasra. I was suggesting that you try using `..` to move back one directory. I haven't tested since I don't have Windows.

Comment: Hey, is there a way to start a process in a specific folder? I plan to ask as question, but I have to wait 90 minutes.

Comment: @CollegeGamer You simply add the keyword `cwd='path'` to your subprocess call. By the way, `subprocess.call` is hardly the right thing to use when working with text files. It is meant to execute, well, executables. Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for input/output

Comment: @greschd Yup. I was just using `.txt`s as an example. The actual file is an executable. Thank for the heads-up though!